# Cannot import name 'Config' from 'mmcv' (unknown location)

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, openmmlab

When I install `mmcv-full`, then python `train.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mmcv import Config, DictAction
ImportError: cannot import name 'Config' from 'mmcv' (unknown location)
```

No matter if I download `mmcv` or `mmcv-full` it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Config has been moved to mmengine in mmcv 2.0.0.
https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv/issues/2757

You can import using:

`from mmengine.config import Config`

Note that as of right now, configs from mmcv <2.0.0 need to be migrated and their tutorials have not been updated in the mmedetection package. So, if you are following those tutorials using Config, you will need to also follow the migration guide:

https://mmdetection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration/config_migration.html